# Select whole words using single finger tap gesture

Tags: macos, trackpad

If you double click a word to select it, and keep the mouse held down, you go it starts word selection mode, meaning it will select whole words as you move the mouse over them.

This only works when using the physical click on the trackpad. The problem is that I want the same behavior using a tap (i.e. the One Finger Tap to Click feature is enabled). When I try to use a tap, though, it goes into character selection mode rather than word selection.

Is there ant way to perform word selection using tap gestures on a trackpad?

Comment: check out bettertouchTool.  Not positive, but I bet there's something in there that would do this.

Comment: @Calavera: I installed it and played around with it's settings for other problems I have. I don't see any settings that might help with this problem though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep!

You double-tap and lift off to select the word.  Then double-tap the selected word and start dragging **immediately** keeping your finger down.  It's actually kind of tricky to get to work without dragging the word but once you get it a couple of times it gets easier.

Here's an explanation on how to do it also from [macworld.com](http://www.macworld.com/article/134513/2008/07/textselect.html), same as above:

> To select text (and this works in nearly any program that involves
> text) on a word-by-word basis, do a double-click-and-hold before you
> start dragging, instead of a single click. As you move the mouse along
> now, you’ll see that entire words are added to your selection as soon
> as the cursor touches their first character. So if you’ve got a fair
> bit of text to select, but still need precision, this is a pretty
> quick way to get it done.

Here are my trackpad settings

[image]

Comment: That causes the word to be dragged rather than highlighting

Comment: it doesn't do anything at all for me except unselect the word

Comment: You have to start the drag almost immediately after the second double-tap.  It works believe me, I just did it.  I know if you delay at all it drags the word instead. I added a link to macworld.com explaining it too

Comment: @calavera: I was able to reproduce that result if I disable one finger dragging in the settings. @Griffo: If I use clicks instead of taps, everything on the macworld article works as described. However, it does not work with taps no matter how many times I try or how fast I do it.

Comment: I just tried it with clicks instead of taps and it worked.  click-click-pause click-click-drag works for me.  You need 'Tap to Click' enabled in preferences.  Do you have that enabled?

Comment: @Senseful,@Griffo: I have tap to click, but none of the dragging settings, set to true.  Probably need to use the drag setting.

Comment: @Griffo Works! But a little complicated.. at least for me

Comment: @Senseful,@Griffo: Yep, that's what made it work!

Comment: @Griffo: I have the exact same settings that you have, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @calavera: I'm confused, you got it to work? I was able to get your results (double tap the second time deselects a word) to work. Not double-tap-and-drag to select whole words (i.e. I still can't get my original problem solved).

Comment: @Senseful: my last comment was in reply to myself.  So basically, when I have the exact same settings as @Griffo's above (plus secondary click), I am able to do what he describes.  I have to do it like he says in the comments though... In other words, start dragging as soon as your finger hits the pad on the second double-tap.  So: tap-tap *pause* tap-tap-drag

Comment: @Griffo: alright, you were right, it's all a matter of timing on how fast you begin dragging after the fourth tap. If you delay even the slightest (what feels like a millisecond at times), you will drag the word. Could you please update the answer to mention that the dragging immediately after the fourth tap is important?

Comment: Yeah it's tricky, answer updated

Answer (score 2):

I'd try using the three finger dragging method. In the Trackpad System Preference, set *Three Fingers* to *Dragging*. Double-tap a word to select it, then use three fingers to drag from that word to highlight more words.

Comment: That works. Unfortunately, though, I like the navigation gesture with three fingers, so I don't want to rebind it.

Comment: This does indeed work in macOS Sierra, but is *very* tricky to get right. Most of my attempts result in whole-paragraph selection.

Answer (score 1):

Double tap **this** word. Then hold shift and double tap **this** word.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't need a second key/hand.

Comment: @Senseful: i don't think you even need a double-tap at the end.  it selected for me with a single tap on the second word.

Comment: @calavera: yeah, that's true.

Comment: @calvera: true, but double tap means you can be less accurate about cursor position (anywhere in the word rather than exactly at the end). Fitt's Law rules.

Comment: @senseful: press shift with your pinky and double tap with your thumb? ;-)

Comment: Nope, not working in macOS Sierra with Magic Trackpad 2.

Comment: Well it did 7 years ago when I created this answer. Unfortunately we can't future proof answers.

Answer (score 0):

On my MacBook I can triple tap (keeping the finger on the pad on the third tap) and drag to use whole word selection.

I can also quadruple tap to select the entire paragraph.

---

My trackpad settings:
[image: trackpad settings]

Comment: That's weird... after reading what you wrote, I tried it and it worked, however that was the only time I could get it to work. No matter what I try, I can't get the same results.

Comment: @Senseful: same here, except it didn't even work once

Comment: Perhaps this is almost same as what @Griffo has said, but for me the other one was easier to do. I am not very good with taps..

Comment: Added trackpad settings for my MacBook for reference, as I have an older machine than @Griffo

Comment: @jtjacques: are you on Leopard (10.5) as well?

Comment: @calvera No, Snow Leopard. I just have an earlier model MacBook that doesn't support those fancy new gestures.