# Double-click-and-drag to select whole words of text, but on trackpad with only touch ( no clicking)

Tags: macos, mac, trackpad, magic-trackpad

With a mouse or trackpad, we can double-click in text to select an entire word. If we hold the pressing of that second click, and then drag, we can select a series of entire words in most text editing places in most apps on macOS.

Is there a way do the same effect (selecting a series of whole words) on a trackpad without the physical clicking, using only touches and taps?

(I want to give my thumb a break from that downward-pressure repetitive motion.)

Using *Apple Magic Trackpad 2* or *MacBook Pro* built-in trackpad, with macOS Sierra.

I tried each of the Answers on this [similar Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/7179/17907). But none of them work. They seem to be outdated, from the Mac OS X era rather than macOS times today.

Comment: Three finger drag is what you can go for. It can be tricky to do at first. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/7190/279727) answer from the same question explains it.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yes, indeed [that Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/7190/279727) does work (double-tap to select, and *immediately* start a 3-finger-drag). But that maneuver is very tricky to get right. Mostly I get whole-paragraph selection instead.  Still, I will mark my Question as a duplicate. Tip: I think the trick is to keep the double-tapping single down, continuing to hold contact with the surface while adding the other 2 fingers for the 3-finger swipe. (but I'm not certain)

Comment: The manoeuvre may require a bit of practise. You can take either one of the two approaches (after enabling three finger drag). First, double tap on a word to select it (using a single finger). Now lift the finger and put three fingers down together on the selected word and then start dragging. Second, no need to select the word first. Simply put down your three fingers together on the trackpad and start dragging. The latter approach is somewhat easier to perform.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Your second approach is for simple text selection, but I am asking about whole-word-incrementing-selection.